# How to specify number of colums in table

Tags: html

I have a table set up as below:

```
 <table border="0">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>*ITEM ONE*</td>
 <td>*ITEM TWO*</td>
 <td>*ITEM THREE*</td>
 <td>*ITEM FOUR*</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>*ITEM ONE*</td>
 <td>*ITEM TWO*</td>
 etc.....
```

I am wanting my items to appear in four colums which they are. However, when I want to re-arrange the items it becomes very tedious copying and pasting them into the `<tr>` that I need and bumping everything forward.

How can I make it so that I simply write something like

```
 <table border="0">
 <tbody>
 <td>*ITEM ONE*</td>
 <td>*ITEM TWO*</td>
 <td>*ITEM THREE*</td>
 <td>*ITEM FOUR*</td>
 <td>*ITEM ONE*</td>
 <td>*ITEM TWO*</td>
 etc.....
```

And they automatically appear in columns of four - so as I add an item - the other items just shift over or into the next rows as needed?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to `bootstrap`?  Use of a scripting language?  Either could help.

Comment: I am not using bootstrap. I'd prefer to not use javascript. I was hoping this was a simple CSS setting but maybe not.

Comment: I think there may be a way with `CSS` but it would be with `divs`, not `tables`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can use `CSS` to do this.  Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jha66oo9/) which demonstrates.

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do it, but you can do it with elements that are set to display as inline-blocks. For example, set an outer div of 100px wide, and then have inner divs set to display as inline-block and 25px (or 25%) wide.

Note: With inline blocks and exact measurements you do need to be careful with the spaces between your divs as they will take up extra room as well.

Comment: Thanks - this was how I did it in the end as well.